# Error run stella vslam with RealSense D435I

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network, realsense, slam

Good afternoon I ran into this problem when running a stella vslam project with RealSense D435I connected. I tried updating the drivers on the camera, and a few configuration files for the camera, nothing helps. The camera works properly, I checked it on several devices, including the device on which I launch the project.

```
--Type for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c

    Thread 9 "run_slam" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    [Switching to Thread 0x7fffe2ffd700 (LWP 18451)]
    0x00007ffff715ba08 in cv::_InputArray::size(int) const () from    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.405
    (gdb) bt
    #0 0x00007ffff715ba08 in cv::_InputArray::size(int) const () at  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.405
    #1 0x00007ffff2a35140 in cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&) ()
at /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4
    #2 0x00007ffff67c1d96 in pangolin_viewer::viewer::run() (this=0x7fffffffd290)
at /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.inl.hpp:81
    #3 0x000055555559cf76 in std::_State_impl<std:    :_Invoker<std::tuple<tracking(std::shared_ptr<stella_vslam_ros::system> const&,     std::shared_ptr<stella_vslam::config> const&, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)::{lambda()#1}> > >::_M_run() ()
    #4 0x00007ffff63b8de4 in () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #5 0x00007ffff6de1609 in start_thread (arg=) at pthread_create.c:477
    #6 0x00007ffff60a5133 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

I run command: gdb -ex r --args /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/stella_vslam_ros/run_slam -v ~/stella_vslam/build/orb_vocab.fbow -c ~/stella_vslam/example/euroc/EuRoC_D435i.yaml --map-db-out ~/my_maps/map.msg

Comment: So this is not your application? The issue seems to be in input passed to imshow.

Comment: That's right, the project is not mine, here is a link to the repository https://github.com/stella-cv/stella_vslam , if necessary, I can provide the camera configuration file

Comment: Maybe you can raise an issue on their repository. The issue is in pangolin_viewer::viewer::run() function. I can see only one imshow in that function in the source code on this [line](https://github.com/stella-cv/stella_vslam/blob/bc035f6a8d970a9fa3cff0a3c932cfe666db7ae6/src/pangolin_viewer/viewer.cc#L130).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! but unfortunately, when trying to open a question, the author of the project abandoned it, here is a link to my question https://github.com/stella-cv/stella_vslam/issues/494

Comment: They closed your issue because you didn't follow their Issue template. I suggest editing as per their issue template and reopening the issue.

Comment: @kiner_shah Unfortunately, my question was again closed and marked as solved, without providing an answer ... https://github.com/stella-cv/stella_vslam/issues/496

Comment: They will close it if you don't follow their issue format template. I recommend really following their issue format template. If you don't follow their process, they won't help you.

Comment: Oh... Could you ask a question according to their template? I don't understand unfortunately :( sorry @kiner_shah

Comment: It's better if you only ask since you are facing the issue. It will be easier to follow up if you raise the issue properly.